# Kubernetes: ignores the secret in helm and shows `certificate signed by unknown authority`

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I created a `secure` private-registry with a self-signed certificate. But I can also login to it using username/password. According to the Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) , the secret types of `kubernetes.io/dockercfg` and `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` are used in order to:

> store the credentials for accessing a Docker registry for images. When you do not have a Docker config file, or you want to use kubectl to create a Docker registry Secret, you can do:

```
sudo k0s kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret-name> \
--docker-username=<username> \
--docker-password=<password>
```

which is what I did and then put the secret inside the deployment helm-chart. Notice that I didn't copy the CA of the registry to the host of docker, helm or kubernetes clients.

Now when I deploy the helm-charts, I get the following error:

> Failed to pull image
> "www.private-registry.com/repo/testimage:2":
> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
> https:// www .private-registry.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by
> unknown authority

Why is it complaining about the certificate even though the secret contains the credentials of the docker-private-registry ?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545732/how-do-i-access-a-private-docker-registry-with-a-self-signed-certificate-using-k

Comment: Which version of K8s are you using? Are you able to pull this image manually?