# How to define certificate to Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, openssl, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a job through jenkins.I am running the deployment.yml file in job.How can I define the pod certificate I created from the deploymenty.yml file? How can I show the certificate to the pod?

```
ERROR kubelet failed to pull image “ip_adress/demo:0.2.0”: rpc error:  code unknown desc= failed to pull and unpack image “ip_adress/demo:0.2.0”: failed to resolve  reference “ip_adress/demo:0.2.0” : failed to do request: head “https://ip_adress/v2demo/manifest/0.2.0” ": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: How is a CA certificate defined? @P....

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access a private Docker registry with a self signed certificate using Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545732/how-do-i-access-a-private-docker-registry-with-a-self-signed-certificate-using-k)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a self-signed certificate for your docker registry instead of the certificate issued by the trusted certificate authority (CA). The docker daemon does not trust the self-signed certificate which causes the x509 error.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-management/2.2.x?topic=tcnm-logging-into-your-docker-registry-fails-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error) for more information.

X.509 digital certificates are a fantastically secure method of authentication, but they require a little more infrastructure to support than your typical username and password credentials. A frequent error encountered by users attempting to configure and install their own certificates is:

“X.509 Certificate Signed by Unknown Authority”

Please refer to this [link](https://www.securew2.com/blog/fix-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error-code) for more information.